# Using RegEx in Google Analytics for Goal Setting - Iss

Tags: regex, google-analytics

[Screenshot of GA goal setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E4du.png)

I'm trying to set up a goal in Google Analytics using regular expression. It's part of an job application funnel that contains 4 steps where the end of the URL equals /en/apply?&step=1. Where 1 is the first step and 4 the confirmation page of the application procedure. I've been trying to make it work but without succes (yet). How should I write this?

This is what I'm ussing now for step 1:

```
https://careers.something.com/job-details-page/en/apply?&step=1 

.*\/en\/apply\?&step=1
```

If it works for step 1 - I'll change it to step 4 and switch the funnel slider for easier interpretation.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? See printscreen below for complete picture.

[image: Printscreen of Google Analytics goal setting]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your regex in **Destination** Field (with *Regular Expressio*n type selected) but with number 4 (because it is the actual goal), like this:

```
.*\/en\/apply\?&step=4
```

Then you can add other step in the funnel (enabling the toggle Funnel), each with the desired number:

```
.*\/en\/apply\?&step=1

.*\/en\/apply\?&step=2

.*\/en\/apply\?&step=3
```

Comment: Thanks Michele. I've added it but it gives a 0% conversion when I verify. Not sure why as I do know that many peope have applied (and therefore been through the funnel). 

Any other ways I can use RegEx?